# Best way to create an SVN-Mirror?

Tags: svn

I am currently looking into the best way to set up an SVN mirror. I currently see three possibilities all with their own drawbacks:

- Have an SVN post-commit-Hook that is blocking and syncing via svnsync. The problem here is obviously, that the commit is blocking until the data is transfered to the mirror.
- Have an SVN post-commit-Hook that is non-blocking and syncing via svnsync. Here I see the following, more subtle problem: Imagine someone checks in a BIG file, and someone else shortly after that checks in a small file. Because the commit is non-blocking, two svnsync processes could be running at the same time and the small file could overtake the BIG file on the way to the mirror (this seems very time-critical and unlikely, although possible in principle). Their revision would swap.
- Sync like every fifteen minutes with a cron-job. Same problem if a commit takes longer than 15 minutes and obviously that time-delay.

Did I forget a possibility? Did I get something wrong? Any ideas? Thank you already!

Maybe I should note that the second possibility is the one suggested by different web-sites. E.g. see
http://www.kirkdesigns.co.uk/mirror-svn-repository-svnsync

Comment: _Because the commit is non-blocking, two svnsync processes could be running at the same time and the small file could overtake the BIG file on the way to the mirror (this seems very time-critical and unlikely, although possible in principle). Their revision would swap._ This is not possible, svnsync replicates commits as they are written to the repository. They will always appear in revision order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try an approach similar to the one we use at Atlassian

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/subversion_replication_at_atla?_ga=2.217251286.1933127788.1517539727-1159165484.1517539727

*disclaimer:* I am currently an Atlassian employee, but was not involved in implementing this solution (only maintaining it)

As I said above in the comment, svnsync, run from a remote repository behaves deterministically. It cannot apply changesets out of order. So the only problem you have using a remote repository is the amount of lag due to changeset propagation.

Comment: +1 for the observation that svnsync cannot get out of order, the only problem is the potential latency.

Comment: You are totally right... I made a stupid thinking mistake. So the simple and beautiful SVN post-commit hook should do it in most cases. In case latency is a problem, one can take a look at the referenced Atlassian article.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Just be aware that the post commit hook will block the committer until the hook has run to completion. I'm not sure what happens if the post commit hook fails, I don't think the commit is rolled back, but it will be at least confusing.

Comment: Well, using the post-commit hook, you can issue a command that immediately returns (e.g. via 'command &' on linux), having it non-blocking. Since the hook is post-commit it cannot rollback the commit. If svnsync fails, the next svnsync has to sync two revisions, which it simply does. The problem occurring here I would file under the topic latency.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla SVN lets you build a repository mirroring solution with the help of hook scripts and the svnsync tool (see [SVNBook | Write-through proxying](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy)). Svnsync-based mirroring [isn't entirely robust](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy.caveats) and has several limitations. E.g., svnsync does not support the lock-modify-unlock versioning model (it does not replicate file locks).

[VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) provides an alternative repository mirroring solution based on the [VDFS (VisualSVN Distributed File System)](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) technology. VDFS helps Subversion admins deploy writable mirrors of Subversion repositories without limitations of svnsync.

Disclaimer: I am a support engineer with VisualSVN Team.